# Why I cant return the value in the method in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I already create a method that can return the value in the excel but when i run the main scripts that call the method, the value cannot be return. Maybe there is a problems with my code but i do not know which part that i need to fix.

This is the script that call the method.

```js
  GetExcel res = new GetExcel();
 String maker = res.getExcel("IS Maker Username");
 GetExcel res1 = new GetExcel();
 String passMaker = res1.getExcel("IS Maker Password");
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")).sendKeys(maker);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(passMaker);
 driver.findElement(By.name("submitLogin")).click();
```

This is the method function

```js
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
@Test
public class GetExcel {
 
 private XSSFWorkbook wb;
 
 public String getExcel(String getName) throws IOException {
  
  File src = new File("C:\\selenium\\ExcelData\\TestData.xlsx");
  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
  wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
  XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
 
  String getValue = null;
  String value = null;
  for (int i = 1; i<=1000; i++) {
   if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0) != null)
   {
     getValue = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
   }
      
      if(getValue != null) {
       if(getValue.contains(getName)) {
        if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1) != null)
        {
          value = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        }
           System.out.println(value);
           fis.close();
           break;
          }  
      } 
      
     }
  return value;
  
  
  
 }

}
```

The method function was imported from different packages

Comment: Have you tried inserting breakpoints and see where is the cause of error yet?

Comment: I have tried and it shows this error  FAILED: usercreation
org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long) and why my excel will be empty after the GetExcel res = new GetExcel(); line?

Comment: Regarding the `EmptyFileException` error check to see if the path to the file is correct -- the error message is quite clear in stating that it tried to open that file but found it to be of 0 bytes size (i.e. empty).

Comment: I already fix the empty file part but there is some issue occurs which when i call the method it shows that this error`'if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0) != null)`. i already change the code in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Your code will always return null value because you are comparing cell value with excel sheet_Name.

2.While you are returning value your second column it should not be empty.

3.If you are trying to fetch any value that is number,you should put ' before number in cell like `'12345`

4. Modified your code Now try.

   `public String getExcel(String getName) throws IOException {`

   ```
       File src = new File("C:\\selenium\\ExcelData\\TestData.xlsx");
       FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
       wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
       XSSFSheet sh1 = wb.getSheet(getName);

       String getValue = null;
       String value = null;
       int number=sh1.getLastRowNum()+1;
       System.out.println("Total used rows :" + number);
       for (int i = 1; i<number; i++) {
           if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0) != null)
           {
                getValue = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
           }

           if(getValue != null) {
               if(!getValue.contains(getName)) {
                   if(sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1) != null)
                   {
                        value = sh1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
                   }
                   System.out.println(value);
                   fis.close();
                   break;
               }   
           }   

       }
       return value;



   }
   ```

Here is the main function call.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GetExcel res = new GetExcel();
        String maker = res.getExcel("IS Maker Username");
        System.out.println("User :" + maker);
        GetExcel res1 = new GetExcel();
        String passMaker = res1.getExcel("IS Maker Password");
        System.out.println("Password :" + passMaker);
    }
```

Please let me know whether it works for you.